# How do i set timeout for a sql present in an application if it has taken more than a certain time period?

Tags: java, sql, unix

In one of my server, there are 3 instances of a particular process(they run daily for around 30 mins and finishes up), now the trouble is sometimes either of them gets stuck in the SQL query and then are stuck forever until I go and manually kill it.Oracle 11g Exadata Server

SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 1800; this will more mess up the situation as I already have our interprocess locks. 
I am looking for some different timeout option if there is any which can be scheduled on properties file in Unix for that server.
Also if any different approach can help me stop the stuck SQL automatically.

```
for i in `jps | grep -i um | cut -d" " -f1`
do ps -eaf | grep $i | grep java | awk 'BEGIN{"date +%H:%M" | getline;d=$0}{print d,$5;e=to_min(d)-to_min($5)
if(e>=120){print e}}
function to_min(a){split(a,b,":")
c=(b[1]*60)+b[2]
return c}'
done
```

um(process name)

Here, I just wrote this script which can be scheduled in crontab so that we can automate it to send an email if any such process is running with that name for longer than 2 hours. But this is not ideally a good approach.

Expecting some option which can be configured so that the long-running SQL gets terminated by itself after 2 hours.

Comment: Well, that might depend on the database server you're using. Postgresql for example has a way to set a statement and/or transaction timeout: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164419/is-it-possible-to-limit-timeout-on-postgres-server - if it's not the statement/transaction itself you could also just watch the processes like you already do and send them a kill command (sigterm) if they are running too long.

Comment: No our's is Oracle 11g Exadata Server.

Comment: As you can see I did make a guess and that guess was wrong. You might thus want to include the information on your DB server into your question via the power of [edit] :)